# SQL windows authentication fails sort of

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

`SQLSERVERABC` is on domain `abc.local`.

If I connect to SQLSERVERABC via remote desktop, I cannot login to the database via SSMS on the local machine that I have remoted to.

At SSMS login screen:

```
Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: SQLSERVERABC
Authentication: Windows Authentication.
User name: abc\mylogin
```

The login attempt will timeout, and the server will not authenticate me or *anyone else* via Active Directory on our domain controller.

The weird thing is Windows Authentication works if I login via SSMS my local computer and not remoted into the SQL server via remote desktop.

But we have remote users who are not on our domain (working from home) they have to remote to the SQL Server and can login using Windows Authentication with their domain credentials but only if they substitute the Server Name: SQLSERVERABC with its IP Address on the SSMS login QUI.

SQLSERVERABC is set to both windows and SQL server authentication, All DNS instances are set up properly...I can not figure out why Windows Authentication will not work when user remote to the actual SQL box unless we use the box's IP address as its Server Name. Yes it's a work around but need fix it...

Trying to get SQL server 2016 that is on a .local domain to allow windows authentication using it's SERVER NAME and not IP address

Comment: `"we have remote users who are not on our domain (working from home) they have to remote to the SQL Server"` Dear God, no, that's awful. **FIND. ANOTHER. WAY.**

Comment: Also, double check the name `SQLSERVERABC` actually resolves to the correct IP from that server, and try entering the fully-qualified server name (`SQLSERVERABC.abc.local`) when logging in. But really: at very **minimum** get another server and let people connect remotely to that, first. Get the user desktop sessions off your sql server directly, and **stop exposing the SQL Server to the public internet.** It's really kind of amazing you haven't been hacked already. It's what the lawyers are likely to eventually call "gross negligence".

Comment: Please post the actual error. A login timeout with vastly different than a connection timeout. Additionally, post the relevant SQL Server errorlog entries for failed logins (18456) with state.

Comment: Why would they need to remote to *the actual server*, why not join them to your network via VPN? If you want to use Windows Authentication, how are you going to do that if these users are not domain-joined?

Comment: One clue is that using an IP forces NTLM.  Also consider having your users use the `runas /netonly` technique to connect from an off-domain client to SQL Server using NTLM, rather than RDP into the server.

Comment: Let me rephrase, I have AD users who access my SQL server from none domain computers via secure VPNs....since their computers are not connected to the domain, they remote to our SQL server and use their AD credentials to login in.  However, on the SSMS splash screen, windows authentication will not work unless the change the SQL server name to it's IP address.  Those of us who are on domain PCs have no issues logging in using Windows Authentication

Comment: It's still **not at all okay** to let people use remote desktop to reach the SQL Server, _even over a VPN_. This will come to tears.